# How to solve react rendering issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using chatGPT to code my website as I'm not a web developer. Last week I tried npm install d3 nd everything went haywire. I also made the rookie mistake of not backing up. after this hiccup npm start wasn't functioning. Now I somehow managed to get that working, but the localhost page shows nothing, it keeps loading but nthing ever comes on the screen.
https://github.com/VinayakSanil/website
This is my github repo

Any and all help would be valuable

I literally have no idea what to do now other than restart the entire thing from scratch

Comment: The github repo is empty

Comment: Please add console errors, if any

Comment: Rashiq bro, you must think I know a lot of stuff, but I don't know. I'm completely out of my field here. All I know is I installed d3 and then it wouldn't work. So I cleared out everything, created a new react project and replaced the src files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the web development field! You are very close to what your want, I must say that it's very impressive for someone new to this is able to get this far. A few things --

1. Your `index.js` also has a `<Router>` on top of another one in `app.js`, which cause error.
2. Your `Route` method in `Routes.js` file is a regular JS function, instead of a JSX function. You need to update `Routes.js` to a JSX file, update the function to be a React component, and actually import `Routes` from `react-router-dom` library instead of out of nowhere.

I managed to fix your app by moving everything in `Routers.js` into `App.js` file (not ideal, but you can reorganize it later). Heres brief idea on how it is fixed --

In `index.js`, remove `<Router>` on line 10 and 14.

Next, update your `Router.js` name to `Router.jsx`

In you `Router.jsx`, modify import --

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and change the function `Routes` to a different name, such as `MyRoutes`. Also make sure to update your export metho name to `MyRoutes` at the bottom of the file.

Now, back to your `App.js` file, update import that was originally for `Routers` to

```
import MyRoutes from './Routes';
```

and then update line 66 `<Routes />` to `<MyRoutes />`

Profit!

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to help. I'll make these changes and give an update